# What is this chime sound that keeps playing at random intervals?

Tags: audio, windows-10, notifications

There is a chiming sound that plays at random intervals on my computer and I cannot figure out for the life of me where it is coming from. Anyone know the origin of [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3jn3fAzjyjtM3ZEczJkNkhNZUE/view?usp=sharing) sound?

edit: Apologies for the poor sound quality. Recorded the sound on my phone through my speakers.

edit: Here is a screenshot of my [Task Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbthB.png)

Comment: We need more info to answer your question. Open Task Manager (Ctrl+Shift+Esc), go to "Details" tab, maximize window, do a screenshot (press Alt+PrtScr, now open Paint, press Ctrl+V, save it), and upload.

Comment: One way to identify it would be to go to the system sounds and play them one at a time.  When you find it, see what use it's identified for.

Comment: It is not a system sound.